# How to add a role to allow updates in realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to update an existing value in Realtime Data Base and I'm getting permission denied error

Here is my code:

```js
async function handleEventCancelation() {
        const eventRef = database.ref(`evento/${eventID}`);

        await eventRef.child(eventID || '').update({
            canceled: 'Y'
        })
    }
```

Here is the role slot:

```
"$eventoId": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth!=null && data.child('authorId').val() == auth.id"
```

Any ideas on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it is 'eventos' instead of 'evento', like this:

```
async function handleEventCancelation() {
    const eventRef = database.ref(`eventos/${eventID}`);

    await eventRef.child(eventID || '').update({
        canceled: 'Y'
    })
}
```